# RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [20, 1, 5, 5], expected input[25, 3, 32, 32] to have 1 channels, but got 3 channels instead

Tags: conv-neural-network

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/te81o.png)

m trying to build a CNN but I get this error:
RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [20, 1, 5, 5], expected input[25, 3, 32, 32] to have 1 channels, but got 3 channels instead

what happened to the code of the con part?
can anyone help me?